# How to get instance ID from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have successfully got permission grant from the below call. I want to get the instance ID after successful grant.How can I get that Id?

```
messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log('Notification permission granted by user.');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Unable to get permission for notification.', err);
  });
```

Comment: Have you gone through the [Access the registration token docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#access_the_registration_token) already? Is there something in the sample that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yeah I have gone through that documentation.But, in docs they are saying like we need to get the instance id after successful permission grant

Comment: See the below link
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client#request_permission_to_receive_notifications

Comment: It says "*Retrieve an Instance ID token for use with FCM*". **Instance ID token** is the same as the **Registration token**. Just follow the docs and you should be fine. :)

Comment: oh... thats fine thanks :)